# Google Scripts API, get "User has not enabled the Apps Script API" even though its enabled

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-apps, google-apps-script-api

I am trying to use the [Google Scripts API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/how-tos/manage-projects).  I run **projects.create** through the npm package and I get the following error:

> Error: User has not enabled the Apps Script API. Enable it by visiting https://script.google.com/home/usersettings then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.

I have visited that page and enabled the API.  I have also enabled the [Apps Script API](https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library/script.googleapis.com?q=script) on the dev console.

Edit: It's been 12 hours now and I keep getting this error. No way the issue is propagation.

Comment: Have you enabled the api for the "project" , that you're trying to use? Api enabling is done per project.

Comment: Yes, correct project, and the API is enabled.  Says "Disable API" there now.

Comment: In your case, for example, when Apps Script API is disabled and that is enabled again, will the situation be changed?

Comment: Disabled both.  got the Error: Apps Script API has not been used in project 597584768224 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting...  Then enabled both again.  And got the same "User has not enabled the Apps Script API"

Comment: Thank you for testing it. I deeply apologize that my proposal didn't change the situation.

Comment: Has the user enabled the API [here](https://script.google.com/home/usersettings) ?

Comment: Yes, I have visited that page and enabled the API for the user.

Comment: Is it the same user? Are you authorized as the same user in the terminal/npm package executor?

Comment: Hmm this might be it.  I'm using a service account to authorize, created under the same google account, but its a different user, its a service account user.  How do I enable that user settings for a service account user?

Comment: The documentation is clear. You **CANNOT** use service accounts

Comment: Well that is **INCREDIBLY** disappointing.

Comment: So basically my Slack Bot, which generates a sheet with data for users, cannot use the Google Script API to add a script to that sheet.